# Getting an error when trying to compare two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a select where i need to make sure that my adate varchar(8) is between two dates supplied.

sometimes the passed in values are NULL so i  would then show everything.

```
select something from myTable where
convert(date, adate) >= ISNULL(convert(date,@beginDate), convert(date, adate))
```

works fine

but when i make it:

```
select something from myTable where
convert(date, adate) >= ISNULL(convert(date,@beginDate), convert(date, adate)) 
and convert(date, adate) <= ISNULL(convert(date,@endDate), convert(date, adate))
```

i get:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

or i can do the <= line without the >= without an error, but not both of them together, what's going on??

the two lines look identical, i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.....

Comment: Ca you give us a sample of data you are using? Which DBMS are you using? As first look i'd say that the endDate has not the same format as the beginDate, but not sure about it.

Comment: Are you using `char`acter data here?

Comment: Why are you converting them? Doesn't `adate <= @beginDate` work? Even if you are using (oh, horror!) `CHAR(8)` for dates, a sane format would hlep avoiding all these conversions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks both @startdate and @enddate are string types. Best thing is to have them in ISO format (yyyymmdd) and you should be fine.

For example try using these;

```
Select @startdate = '20130101', @enddate = '20130221'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what you're trying to do but... 
Since any of the values could come by NULIFIED, you said you would get every result in the table... so it might be easier just to set the query to filter it on the language you're using before the DB...

Or as I would put on a PHP sample...

```
    IF ( !$beginDate || !$endDate )
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    }
    ELSE
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 'whatever clause'";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your value for @endDate.  That parameter is your only difference between the SELECT that works, and the one that doesn't.  Chances are, it (sometimes) contains a value that cannot be converted to a date.  Usual suspect is the empty string (`''`)